# PHP using an isset and SESSION to display content on the screen

Tags: php, html

Hello all this is a follow up to a previous question, as explained I have created an exam using PHP and radio buttons. I have successfully passed the variable so they are calculated and displayed on screen using the GET method and echo prompt.

My problem is when a new user views the page I get an error message prompting that the variable totalscore is undefined. I understand that this happens because this variable currently does no exist because there is no variable for the GET method. I'm trying to achieve "Total score: 20%" when there a result, but blank when there isnt.

I have researched that I should use the isset and SESSION command to create an if statement:

```
<? $totalScore=$_GET['totalscore']; ?>

<? if (isset($_SESSION['totalscore']))

{
echo "Total Score";
echo $totalScore;
echo "&#37;";
}
else
{}
?>
```

Forgive me if this code is completely wrong, my understanding is that if there is a variable 'totalscore' in the session the page will echo the information, and if there is not nothing will be displayed.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable notices, or:

```
<?php $totalScore = isset($_GET['totalscore']) ? $_GET['totalscore'] : false; ?>
```

also you should be doing something like if($totalScore) { do whatever }

:)

Comment: Thanks for your time and response - appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First Page

```
if (isset($_GET['totalscore'])) {
    // grab data
    $totalScore = $_GET['totalscore'];
    // store in session
    $_SESSION['totalscore'] = $totalScore;
}
```

Second Page or Same Page

```
// check the session and use
if (isset($_SESSION['totalscore'])) {
    echo "Total Score";
    echo $_SESSION['totalscore'];
    echo "&#37;";
} else {
    // session not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To [prevent session hijacking](http://www.thecodertips.com/2012/09/session-security-tutorial-protection.html) you must add:
`<?
session_start();
?>`
at the beginning

also learn to secure sessions